# EF Core dynamic operator in Where condition

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have this ugly piece of code

```cs
if (request.TipoConfronto == ETipoConfronto.Uguale)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Cognome))
        query = query.Where(x => x.Cognome == request.Cognome);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Nome))
        query = query.Where(x => x.Nome == request.Nome);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.CodFisc))
        query = query.Where(x => x.CodFisc == request.CodFisc);
}
else if (request.TipoConfronto == ETipoConfronto.Inizia)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Cognome))
        query = query.Where(x => x.Cognome.StartsWith(request.Cognome));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Nome))
        query = query.Where(x => x.Nome.StartsWith(request.Nome));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.CodFisc))
        query = query.Where(x => x.CodFisc.StartsWith(request.CodFisc));
}
else if (request.TipoConfronto == ETipoConfronto.Contiene)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Cognome))
        query = query.Where(x => x.Cognome.Contains(request.Cognome));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Nome))
        query = query.Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(request.Nome));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.CodFisc))
        query = query.Where(x => x.CodFisc.Contains(request.CodFisc));
}
```

Here I set the conditions on three fields using a different operator based on a parameter (TipoConfronto).
The operator may be Equals, StartsWith or Contains.

How can I change this code to dynamically change the operator type to avoid code duplication?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With function below you can do the following:

```cs
query = query.Filter(request.Cognome, x => x.Cognome, request.TipoConfronto);
query = query.Filter(request.Nome,    x => x.Nome,    request.TipoConfronto);
query = query.Filter(request.CodFisc, x => x.CodFisc, request.TipoConfronto);
```

And implementation:

```cs
public static class FilterExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string value, Expression<Func<T, string>> stringField, ETipoConfronto tipoConfronto)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return query;

        var valueConstant = Expression.Constant(value);

        var body = stringField.Body;
        switch (tipoConfronto)
        {
            case ETipoConfronto.Uguale:
                body = Expression.Equal(body, valueConstant);
                break;
            case ETipoConfronto.Inizia:
                body = Expression.Call(body, nameof(string.StartsWith), Type.EmptyTypes, valueConstant);
                break;
            case ETipoConfronto.Contiene:
                body = Expression.Call(body, nameof(string.Contains), Type.EmptyTypes, valueConstant);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(tipoConfronto), tipoConfronto, null);
        }

        var predicateLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, stringField.Parameters);

        return query.Where(predicateLambda);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Svyatoslav Danyliv. Your code is perfect if the property is in the main table (e.g. x.Cognome). 

But now I need to check the field Cognome in a related table. Somehting like this: 
query = query.Where(x => x.MainTable.Any(y => y.RelatedTableNavigation.Cognome == request.Cognome));
Do you think it is possible to handle a case like this?